# UITableViewController customCell disappear and appear as they wish both on scroll and load

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been looking for answers for more than 2 days now. It just does not seem to solve.

Here is the code for cell

```
- (myCustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomData *m = (CustomData *)[self.allCustomData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    myCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f green:255.0f blue:255.0f alpha:1]];
    [cell.customTitle setText:m.name];
    [cell.customStatus setText:@"Download"];

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.customTitle.text);

    return cell;
}
```

'cell' never returns nil. the log always prints the correct text. But the cells appear empty for some reason. On load I notice the first cell appears empty, and then on scroll, randomly 2-3 cells of any order become empty. The first cell often appears back on scroll.

I can't seem to understand what the issue could be.

---

UPDATE

Here are two screen shots. First one is how the table loads, I have put a background color just for debugging purpose. As you see the first cell is not showing up.

[image]

The one below is the second screenshot where I changed the orientation and scrolled a bit. You see how the first cell magically appears and the second goes away.

[image]

Also for debugging purpose, I added these two methods.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(dtEditionCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"Display %@ %d %f",cell.editionTitle.text,indexPath.row,cell.frame.origin.x);


}
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(dtEditionCell *)cell   forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"End Display %@ %d %f",cell.editionTitle.text,indexPath.row,cell.frame.origin.x);
}
```

The log prints as expected. All cells are visible with correct text.

Comment: This scrolling behaviour is because cells are being reused in a tableView. By having the same identifier for each cell you are saying iOS, "Hey, these are identical, please reuse them". It might be that your CustomData object is nil which causes names to appear empty.

Comment: If nil how can the log print correct output

Comment: Perhaps the cells get messed up because you do not create a new one if no cell is available for reuse. Make sure you have that you create a new one if cell is nil. Try adding `if(cell==nil) {
cell = [[myCustomCell alloc] init]; }`

Comment: have you set the cell identifier in your xib/storyboard ?

Comment: While you scroll Tableview DataSource methods calls. So it reloads the table data. Now from your issue it looks like while Table reloads at that time your array value also changes.

Comment: may dequeue a standard tableViewCell, and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it has something to do, but the method you show is not exactly the one used by the tableview. Here is how I do it with custom cells. I'm doing it a lot and works fine:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    TextCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    TextFieldContent *cellContent=[[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text=cellContent.titleLabel;
    cell.textField.placeholder=cellContent.placeHolder;
    cell.textField.tag=cellContent.tag;
    cell.textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    cell.textField.delegate=self;

    return cell;

}
```

TextFieldContent is a cutom object that hold all the properties of the custom cell. For easier implementation.